# Problem with using custom fields to contain a link which would be accessed on a product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, wordpress-shortcode

I want to put a PDF link in a custom field, which would then be accessed for a button on the single product page.

```php
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'product_link', true); ?>" target="_blank" class="wp-block-button__link has-text-color has-background has-text-align-center wp-element-button" style="color:#fefbfb;background-color:#5ce1e6" rel="noopener">View Product</a>
```

The button part works, I removed the `href` part and it displayed. But for some reason, it won't insert the link from the custom field.

Overall, I have an online bookstore and I want to provide a sample for each book. I used this code in the product description initially.

```php
<a href="insert pdf link" target="_blank" class="wp-block-button__link has-text-color has-background has-text-align-center wp-element-button" style="color:#fefbfb;background-color:#5ce1e6" rel="noopener">Sample</a>
```

However, I now want to place the button under the product image.

I don't want to go into the files for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should embed your button in a shortcode, that you can use everywhere on a product page.

**The code:**

```php
add_shortcode  ('product_button', 'product_button_shortcode' ); 
function product_button_shortcode(){
    if( ! is_product() ) return; // Only on single product pages
    
    return sprintf('<a href="%s" target="_blank" class="%s" style="%s" rel="noopener">Sample</a>',
        esc_html( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'product_link', true) ),
        'wp-block-button__link has-text-color has-background has-text-align-center wp-element-button',
        'color:#fefbfb; background-color:#5ce1e6;'
    );
}
```

code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme), or using also the plugin [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) too.

**Usage:**

- As a simple shortcode `[product_button]` in the product description editor for example
- Or using `echo do_shortcode("[product_button]");` in PHP

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to try and avoid going into the php file if possible. If not then I might have to stick with what I have at the moment

Comment: You can also use instead the plugin [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/), recommended by WooCommerce. As this answer works and answer your initial question, could you please accept this answer (To mark an answer as accepted,
 click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in), thank you.